# Apply a list of regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a long list of regular expressions in an ignore.txt, and another long list in an include.txt file.  What would be the quickest way to apply these using PHP against data contained in a sample.html file such that any matches found in include are captured, but then anything matching in ignore.txt is excluded?

Comment: preg_match and preg_replace accept arrays as arguments so that you can run lists of expressions through them. how to tunr your text files into arrays depends on how your txt files are formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your include.txt and ignore.txt files are setup so that they're only regular expressions, and there's one expression per line, you can use PHP's `file()` function. That will load the files into an array where each individual line is an element in the array. You can use `file_get_contents()` to load the sample.html file in as a string.

`preg_match()` or `preg_match_all()` do *not* actually take arrays as input, like `preg_replace()` does. You will need to loop over your array of expressions using something like `foreach` and applying an individual call to one of the matching functions to get your results.

I think `preg_match_all()` will suit your needs best, because it sounds like you're wanting to pull all of the matches out of the entire file, not just the first one. Once you have your full list of matches, then you'd apply your filter using the data from ignore.txt in a similar manner.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, but wondered if there might be a clever way I hadn't thought of as opposed to looping through each line in each file.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the quickest way would be to let the shell do the job

```
$result = `cat sample.html | egrep -f include.txt | egrep -vf ignore.txt`;
```

Comment: Two problems with this answer: 1. You can't really assume that this person isn't using Windows. 2. He asked for a PHP solution.